# Magento 2 - Setting "Text Swatch" or "Visual Swatch" does not work. Attribute still shows as dropdown on frontend

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, magento2.2.3, swatches

I am trying to create basic text swatches for an attribute (instead of dropdowns). I created an attribute (for example, "size"), set the "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" to "Text Swatch" and entered all the swatch values. I then created a configurable product with this attribute but the frontend is still showing the options in a dropdown and not in text swatches.

I have tried changing the attribute to "visual swatch" and it still shows as a dropdown.

I have reindexed and flushed the cache but it the attribute choices still show as a dropdown.

Interestingly, the text swatches are showing up in the category page but the product page is still showing the dropdown (see images below).

I am using Magento 2.2.3 and I am not running any extensions and the code has not been changed. It is almost a fresh install.

How can I get the text swatches to show up instead of a dropdown?

Please help

[image: Product Page - options **incorrectly** showing as dropdown]

[image: Category Page - options **correctly** showing as text swatches]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! I disabled a certain "Pre Order" extension I had been using and now the swatches show up. The extension must have been interfering with the magento swatch rendered.

I am posting this just in case someone else runs into this issue so that they do not have to waste as much time as I did.

Answer (score 2):

To change the display type to Text Swatch, navigate to

> Dashboard > Stores > Attributes > Product

then find the '**size**' attribute from the table.
[image]
[image]

Change the "**Catalog Input Type for Store Owner**" to **Text** Swatch
[image]

You should now see a new column appear in the **Manage Swatch section**.

> Add the values that you would like to show inside the swatches, then
>   click Save.

All items that use the **size attribute** will now display a text swatch instead of a **drop-down** menu.

Comment: thank you for responding. Yes, I have done all of those steps to a new attribute I had made and the product page is still showing the options of this attribute in a dropdown instead of in text swatches

Comment: `rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ `

Comment: `rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/ `

Comment: and let me if after running this command, it still doesn't work

Comment: I tried both commands and flushed the cache again and it still shows as a dropdown and not text swatches... this is very peculiar... what else can the issues be?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with changing "Storefront Properties" in Attribute Settings. Set "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" to "Yes" and "Used in Product Listing" to "Yes".
After that reindex product data again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Text swatch showed in the filter column of a category page,
but didn't show in product page.

For me the answer was the right cache flush.
Note: On the chache management page, there are several flush options.
The one that worked was "Flush Cache Storage". (The grey option)
It gives a warning, but worked fine for me.

Now, i can toggle between input type (Dropdown / Visual swatch / text swatch) whith direct result, without a cache flush.